# How to aggregate only unique and not null values from column into a JSON array?

Tags: postgresql

Suppose I have a table like this:

```
| id | linked_id | another_id |
|----|-----------|------------|
| 1  | 1         | 1          |
| 1  | 2         | null       |
| 1  | 3         | 1          |
```

I would like to aggregate results by `id` - collect `linked_id`s and `another_id`s into a JSON objects. So in the end what I would like to get is this:

```
id: 1
linked_ids: [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }]
another_ids: [{ id: 1 }]
```

Notice how in the case of `another_id` only unique ids were aggregated and `null` got ignored. I'm able to achieve this with regular arrays by using:

`array_agg(distinct another_id) filter (where another_id is not null)`.

However I need to get JSON array of objects in the end, not regular one. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `jsonb_agg()` instead:

```
select id, 
       jsonb_agg(linked_id) as linked_ids, 
       jsonb_agg(distinct another_id) filter (where another_id is not null) as other_ids
from the_table
group by id;
```

If you want a single JSON value for each row (=group) you can use `to_jsonb()`

```
select to_jsonb(r)
from (
  select id, 
         jsonb_agg(linked_id) as linked_ids, 
         jsonb_agg(distinct another_id) filter (where another_id is not null) as other_ids
  from the_table
  group by id
) r
```

Or using `jsonb_build_object()`

```
select jsonb_build_object(
         'id', id, 
         'linked_ids', jsonb_agg(linked_id),
         'other_ids', jsonb_agg(distinct another_id) filter (where another_id is not null)
       )
from the_table
group by id
```

Comment: It's crucial for me to have it the other way around - array of objects, not object of arrays. In real world scenario these ids are uuids and in the end I need to be able to do a partial match queries for autocomplete input on them.